# How to move upsells to sidebar?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, static-block, product-view, sidebar

I want to move the upsells block to the (left) sidebar on the product page.
The content of the left-sidebar is a static block containing HTML.

[image]

Edited the catalog.xml already(Product view section)

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <!--
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
            -->
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>

            <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
                    <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
            </block>

            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <refrence name="left">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
            <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
            </block>
    </refrence>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<catalog_product_view>   
<refrence name="left">
  <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">

                <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
            </block>
 </refrence>
</catalog_product_view>
```

for hack way go to this path and write this code
`app\design\frontend\yourPackage\yourTheme\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtml.`

and add below line

```
if(Mage::registry('current_product'))
{
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_upsell')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml')->toHtml();
 }
```

add this code in your local.xml file or any custom module layout file this will show in your product page only

Comment: Doesn't work, when i paste only the block inside <catalog_product_view>  without the <refrence name="left"> it shows on the product view tho.

Comment: have you try with <refrence name="left"> becuse I think you miss refrence name only

Comment: Yes, i copied your code with the <refrence name="left">

Comment: Some where has code to remove upsell from left find in your xml files

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Its remoeved from some where please check your layouts one by one

Comment: find this line `upsell_products` in all your layout and comment remove code and check

Comment: Checked every layout, there is no upsell_products. only in catalog.xml

Comment: Check My updated answer

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know its working or not